# How to read the text file and generate the html file using php?

Tags: php, html

i am using the text file where i am going to update the text file every day.so i want these text to be on html file with formatting. how can i generate the html file using text file? can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether you want to style paragraphs or each line from your txt file,

If each line, then you can have:

```
$myfile = 'filetoread.txt';
$lines = file($myfile);    
for($i=count($lines);$i>0;$i--){
    echo "<span class='yourstyleclass'> $lines[$i] </span>";
}

if paragraphs

$myfile = 'filetoread.txt';
$lines = file($myfile);

$lines = str_replace(array("\n\n", "\n\r"), "</p><p>", $lines);
echo "<p>$lines</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents($file_location)`

Please Visit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have this in your "text_file.txt":

```
<div>
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Some short paragraph...</p>
</div>
```

All you need to do is:

```
echo file_get_contents("text_file.txt");
```